# ManagementObject GetInstances() exception

Tags: .net, volume, drive

Environment: Windows Forms Application, C# .NET 3.5, VS2008

When I call the following function from inside an overridden WndProc handler I get this exception on the mc.GetInstances() line "COMExcepion was unhandled - The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"

This far more cryptic message actually shows before the previously mentioned exception:

"DiconnectedContext was detected - Context 0x3333b40 is disconnected.  No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component. This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay alive until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that live inside them."

```
private bool IsRemovableDevice(char dl)
 {
  ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
  ManagementObjectCollection partitions = mc.GetInstances();
  string bleh = "";
  foreach (ManagementObject p in partitions)
  {
  if (Convert.ToString(p["Caption"])[0] == dl && (int)p["DriveType"] == 2)
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }
```

Here's the deal, that function listed above works fine when it is called from any context other than a WndProc function.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Have you got Windows Management Instrumentation installed and the service running on the host machine?

Comment: That's not included on a machine running .NET 3.5?  Here's the deal, that function listed above works fine when it is called from any context other than a WndProc function.

Comment: WMI is a Windows component, not a .NET component.  It's also an optional component.

Comment: Why does it crash when called from WndProc but not, from say, a Form_Click event handler?

Comment: not sure, but `WndProc` is called in a tight loop - how many times does your WMI code execute and is there any good reason for it to be in `WndProc`?

Comment: Well, it will crash from any execution that that begins in WndProc and I do need it to be in that execution thread because I'm looking for a message that indicates a device (specifically a removable type volume) has arrived on the system. Even if I invoke the function from WndProc, it crashes.

Comment: I could monitor a flag from a timer instantiated in the main thread and then call the function but that seems like a kludge way of tackling this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the error, but I found this on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/bbe38513-977c-456f-ae81-9b8c2aa1feb1

Not sure if it will help you.

I'd review the need to put that sort of stuff in `WndProc`, WMI can sometimes be expensive.  It might be better to use a relatively quick timer instead of the UI message pump.

A quick search around WMI events and detecting removable drives finds these sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179315.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/13/how-can-i-determine-when-a-removable-drive-gets-connected.aspx

Comment: Yeah I'm beginning to warm up to a polling timer but that just feels really kludge.  Ah well.

Comment: @Mark `WndProc` is doing the same but without a timer.  Perhaps you can use WMI events, I've added some links.

Comment: Also, to answer your previous question,  the private bool IsRemovableDevice(char dl)  method is only called if a device arrival message is received...in other words...not very often.